# Is GET method is faster than POST?

Tags: php, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why GET method is faster than POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211881/why-get-method-is-faster-than-post)

I use both methods for transfering data but not decide which is faster and recommended.

Answer (score 6):

GET may be considered *slightly* faster in that it contains less overhead, but the difference should be essentially negligible.  The difference between the two is based on other factors.  There's lots of discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get).

Answer (score 4):

The choice of method ought to be made on what the action is doing not on which is faster.  Use GET for actions that obtain data.  Use POST for actions that create/modify data.  Using a GET for an action that creates or modifies data can have awful consequences if the URL is bookmarked.

Comment: Not just if the URL is bookmarked; using GET for destructive actions can actually enable a security vulnerability (cross-site request forgery)