# What is more efficient in terms of data consumption. GET or POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, post, get

Assuming we want to send the some data from a device (IOT) to our server. Small no. of variables (say 10 to 20) but updated per second.
So sent to the server a large no. of times. (Say 60 times a minute)
What should I use so that minimum of my data pack is used. (Sending using GPRS)
GET or POST?

Comment: They are equally effective, but in respect to REST, you should use AJAX post request.

Comment: Any differences are trivial compared to network time. Maybe you should benchmark it with your actual hardware and payloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE :**

You should check this thread : [Why GET method is faster than POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211881/why-get-method-is-faster-than-post)

In fact POST use a little bit more data because the header contain some more info like the type of content and it's length

```
POST /blog/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name1=value1&name2=value2
```

**OLD :**

GET requests:

```
GET /blog/?name1=value1&name2=value2 HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
```

POST requests:

```
POST /blog/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

As you can see there is no big difference in term of length so both request should use the same ammount of data.
GET have some limitaion for the url length (2048) and it can only contain ASCII

Source : http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Answer (score 0):

Well technically and according to multiple answers in this question :
[When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

GET is generally used to retrieve data **from** a server and POST to submit data **to** a server. So in your use case you might want to use POST instead of GET.

But generally POST is slower and would be bigger in size than a GET request. That is if the data send in both requests is identical.