# URL parameter vs post form data

Tags: rest, api, django-rest-framework

URL parameter or post form data; which is more computationally efficient for a backend API to query?

example:

```
GET : user/:id

POST: user/ { "id": "some_id" }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Comment: I am not really convinced that this has any significant impact performance-wise. Usually compared to database queries, middleware, etc. the number of cycles to decode the data is insignificant.

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate of that because I know the difference between `GET` & `POST`. A same task can be solved by both GET` and `POST`. My question is which is computationally more efficient avoiding all other things. @Erumaru

Comment: @ATMRagibRaihan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211881/why-is-the-get-method-faster-than-post-in-http

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409014/what-is-more-efficient-in-terms-of-data-consumption-get-or-post?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, the difference will be very insignificant practically. But I am just curious to know which is more efficient theoretically. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Well just don't use POST when you're meant to use GET. It's a standard. What you should be comparing is `GET : user/:id` and `GET: user/?id=some_id` instead, if you do just want to filter with the id. Filtering with form data is just outrightly wrong